# Links aren't working inside a dynamic div ( loaded with jquery .load() )

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

My problem is I have many links inside the loaded `div` and they aren't clickable after load.
I saw some similar question but couldn't understand how to use that in my problem.

I'm trying to make a `lightbox` kind of effect (no plugins just simply using .load() to load contents to a div, everything works but the links inside the loaded div.

```
<div class="post">
  <a class="layer" href="/post/123 #the_post>*">
</div>

$('.layer').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var path = $(this).attr('href');
      $('#overlay_content').load(path, function(){
          $(".media").each(function(){
              var medhei = $(this).height();
              $(this).css("line-height", medhei + 'px');
          });
      });
});
```

Also tried something like this but didn't work:

```
$('.layer').live('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var path = $(this).attr('href');
      $('#overlay_content').load(path, function(){
          $(".media").each(function(){
              var medhei = $(this).height();
              $(this).css("line-height", medhei + 'px');
          });
      });
});
```

Comment: Please check href value

Comment: Parag, i think they are fine, and they works as they should when i open the page itself, just doesn't work when loaded with jquery. I am able to right click and open in new tab though but that's not good interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out a quick solution, hope it'll help people who have similar problem.
In simple words i just made the link open the location it's href attribute has, on click.

```
$('.layer').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var path = $(this).attr('href');
      $('#overlay_content').load(path, function(){
          $(".media").each(function(){
              var medhei = $(this).height();
              $(this).css("line-height", medhei + 'px');
          });
          $("#overlay_content a").click(function(){
              window.location=$(this).attr('href');
              return false;
          });
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax to delegate event using `.on()` method (jq 1.7 >) is:

```
$(document.body).on('click','.layer',function(e) {...});
```

Now you shouldn't delegate to body level but to the closest static container where you load new elements. So i guess:

```
$('#overlay_content').on('click','.layer',function(e) {...});
```

Comment: When i use this, it just opens the content page rather loading some part to the (#overlay_content) div. Any idea, what might be the problem?
Thank you for help.

Comment: Looks like default behaviour of anchor click is not prevented. Your code suggest you are using e.preventDefault(); so i'm not sure it is your issue here.

Comment: Yep, for now figured out a quick solution. Thank you.

Comment: @ialok so you have find a solution to your issue? If ya, please provide it as answer in order to help (maybe) futur readers

Comment: Yes, i tried, it says i have to wait 3 hours cause i do not have enough reputation to post the answer. I'll do it. )

Comment: @a-wolff You're welcome. Your answer was helpful too, i didn't know much about 'delegate event' before, will vote it helpful when i can. Just posted the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is delegated event handlers, however .live is deprecated, try:

```
$(container).on("event","link_selector",function() {
  // Your stuff
});
```

For example something like:

```
$(document).on("click",".layer",function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var path = $(this).attr('href');
   $('#overlay_content').load(path, function(){
       $(".media").each(function(){
           var medhei = $(this).height();
           $(this).css("line-height", medhei + 'px');
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: It's not working, everything is same and links aren't clickable. Thank you for help.

Comment: if the links have the class ".layer" and they are inside the document element (exist somewhere in the body of the html document) then there is no reason for the event handlers not to work. Check your console, see if the code inside the event handler is working correctly.

Comment: I know it should work. Yes, checked with firefox console, it's just blank. Thank you.